# Transforming a list into pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, list, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using pyspark 2.1,I am trying to find some predicted result and the code is given below

```
restultSet=testingData.map(lambda p: (p.label, linearModel.predict(p.features))).collect()
```

Now the output of restultSet is in list and it looks like below

```
[(2.0, array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, array([ 2.09078012])), (1.0, array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, array([ 2.09078012])), (1.0, array([ 2.09078012]))]
```

When I am have give type(restultSet) it is showing me below result

I am struggling to convert from list to dataframe

I tried to use below snippets it didn't work . Please help

```
restultSet.toDF()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert `restultSet` to a Spark dataframe because, due to `collect`, it is a *Python list*, and `toDF` works for RDDs.

Removing `collect`, and adding one more `map` to convert your numpy arrays to `Vectors.dense` should do the job.

Here is an example with the data you have provided:

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

# your data as an RDD (i.e. before 'collect')
dd = sc.parallelize([(2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (1.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (1.0, np.array([ 2.09078012]))])
dd.take(1)
# [(2.0, array([ 2.09078012]))]

df = dd.map(lambda x: (x[0], Vectors.dense(x[1]))).toDF()
df.show()
# +---+------------+ 
# | _1|          _2|
# +---+------------+
# |2.0|[2.09078012]| 
# |2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |1.0|[2.09078012]|
# |2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |1.0|[2.09078012]|
# +---+------------+
```

To give names to the resulting columns, include them as a list argument in `toDF`, i.e. `toDF(["column_1", "column_2"])`.

Comment: My intention was `.toDf` on `List`(Not on Rdd). As it will comes only with implicits in scala. Anyways thanks for pointing out.